# Clicking on UITextField makes UIScrollView Smaller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a `UIScrollView` and in the `UIScrollView` I have `UITextFeild`'s in that `UIScrollView`. My problem is that after clicking on the `UITextfFeild` the `UIScrollView` becomes smaller than what I set it to.

I set my `UIScrollView`:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (320,800);
}
```

When I click on the `UITextfeild` the `UIScrollView` goes from being 800 to smaller about 500?

```
#import "TestViewController.h"

@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController
AVAudioPlayer *player;

@synthesize myScrollView;
@synthesize questionLabel, actionBarLabel, questionPlaceholder, commentsLabel;
@synthesize imageView, firstNameTextField,commentsTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 0.0;
myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.0;
myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myScrollView.delegate = self;
[myScrollView addSubview:imageView];
[myScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
[myScrollView addSubview:questionLabel];
[myScrollView addSubview:firstNameTextField];
[myScrollView addSubview:commentsTextField];
[myScrollView addSubview:actionBarLabel];
[myScrollView addSubview:questionPlaceholder];
[myScrollView addSubview:commentsLabel];

UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 600.0f, 300.0f, 42.0f)];
[btn1 setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Choose an Option"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(showActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.myScrollView addSubview:btn1];

[self performSelector:@selector(showGradientForQuestions1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *imageData = [defaults dataForKey:@"image"];
UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

NSString *frontName = [defaults objectForKey:@"firstname"];
NSString *comments = [defaults objectForKey:@"commentsText"];

// Update the UI elements with the saved data
imageView.image = contactImage;
firstNameTextField.text = frontName;
commentsTextField.text = comments;
firstNameTextField.delegate = self;
commentsTextField.delegate = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction) save:(id)sender
{
[firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[commentsTextField resignFirstResponder];

// Create instace of NSData
UIImage *contactImage = imageView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(contactImage, 100);
NSString *frontName = [firstNameTextField text];
NSString *comments = [commentsTextField text];

// Store the data
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];
[defaults setObject:frontName forKey:@"firstname"];
[defaults setObject:comments forKey:@"commentsText"];

[defaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"Data saved");

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Data Saved!" message:@" Successfully saved to cache" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
imageView = nil;
firstNameTextField = nil;
commentsTextField = nil;
myScrollView = nil;
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[firstNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
[commentsTextField resignFirstResponder];
[imageView resignFirstResponder];
[myScrollView resignFirstResponder];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];

return YES;
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake (320,800);
}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: why do you want your scroll view to be so much taller than the actual contents of the view?

Comment: Because I am going to need that space to be filled out eventually. For the Moment if you see  I have put a button at 600, but it is hidden in the image and I cannot scroll to the button at 600 after editing the text field.

Comment: Are you sure that your scoroll's contentSize get smaller or the scroll view scrolls up ?

Comment: Yes the UIScrollview scrolls up, but when I want to scroll down to the button again, It will not let me.

Comment: What you wrote inside the text field delegate methods?

Comment: Are you adding views from XIB? If yes, 1.) Check for autosizing of scroll view that could be messing up the scroll view frame & 2.) Why are you explicitly adding subviews to your scroll view, have you not done this in XIB already?

Comment: I am using the Storyboard. When I use a xib it is fine. Maybe something in the storyboard is messing with it?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibly because your scrollView clips to bounds?

```
myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Nah sorry tried to comment out clip to bounds. Didn't work same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on textview or textfield, keyboard comes and hides part of the screen and you wont be able to scroll the rest of the view until the keyboard goes. Try increasing the height of the scroll view in the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` function and decrease the same amount in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` function.

```
scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width,scrollView.contentSize.height+KeyBoardSizePixel);
```